# How to get properties for multiple users using Get-ADUser

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I was trying to get info on multiple users using Get-ADUser but it doesn't like it. Can someone provide a tip on how to do this? Many Thanks

```
Get-ADUser -Identity jdoe, jsmith, adoe, bdoe, cdoe -Properties  CN, SamAccountName ,passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires | select  SamAccountName, passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires
```

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by the cmdlet help, Identity does not accept an array of input:

```
Get-ADUser [-Identity] <ADUser> [-AuthType {Negotiate | Basic}] [-Credential <pscredential>]
   [-Partition <string>] [-Properties <string[]>] [-Server <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

So, you can loop over an array of input:

```
'jdoe','jsmith','adoe','bdoe','cdoe' | ForEach-Object { 
     Get-AdUser -Identity $_ -Properties PasswordLastSet,PasswordNeverExpires}
```

Or you can run against an entire OU:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com" -SearchScope Subtree
```

Or construct an appropriate LDAPFilter

```
Get-AdUser -LDAPFilter '(|(sAMAccountName=*doe)(sAMAccountName=jsmith))'
```

Or any number of other ways.  But your best bet is always the help.  If you don't have it downloaded, there's always:

```
 Get-Help Get-AdUser -Online
```

You should be able to find examples, if not, these should give you an idea of where to start: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps&redirectedfrom=MSDN#examples

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can run it against multiple users by doing:

```
@('user1','user2','etc') | get-aduser | select-object Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will get you all the properties of the user

```
Get-ADUser usernamehere -Properties * | Select-Object name,office
```

you can add the Select object to define the information you want to see

```
Get-ADUser usernamehere -Properties *  | Select-Object name,office
```

Comment: I used a poweshell script that users a CSVfile with the attributes I want to retrieve, $OU = "OU=ouname External Users,DC=corp,DC=name-group,DC=com" 

$CSVname = "C:\Users\myaccount\Documents\UKOUusers.csv" 
#Import-Module ActiveDirectory #Imports AD module

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Filter * -Properties GivenName,Surname,EmailAddress,Department,Manager,Office| Select GivenName,Surname,EmailAddress,Department,Manager,Office| Export-Csv $csvname